# Get only 10 values instead of all - Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I started learning more in detail in Rxjs. I was trying different codes then I have the below code expecting to get only 10 records but to my surprise, it was all.

```js
todos: Observable<TodoItem[]>;

constructor(private http: HttpServiceService) {
  this.todos = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  this.todos.pipe(
    map((todoList) => todoList.map(todo => ({ ...todo, id: todo.id + 10 }))),
    take(10)
  ).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

So can someone please explain why it didn't took 10 and how we can make it to get only 10 records?

Thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `take` operator emits a specified number of values from an observable and then completes. please read about the take operator [here](https://operator%20is%20used%20to%20emit%20a%20specified%20number%20of%20values%20from%20an%20observable%20and%20then%20complete)

in your example, the API call returns an array

to take get first 10 records you can do like this

```
this.todos = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
this.todos.pipe(
 map((todoList) => todoList.map(todo => ({ ...todo, id: todo.id + 10 }))),
 map((todoList) => todoList.slice(0, 10))
)
.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, api call will return an array. It will return single value that is an array. In your stream there will be one value (single array) and then stream ends.

So take(10) will do nothing in your case. Take operator would work if your stream have multiple values and then you put some "limit" on number of values going to your "subscribe" block before stream ends.

So solution of your problem is not related to rxjs, its basic js array manipulation.

You can just return

```
todoList.map(todo => ({ ...todo, id: todo.id + 10 })).slice(0, 10)
```